# Sonar interfacing with Raspberry Pi - getting problem with C code

Tags: raspbian

Here is code from [RPi: HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor mini-project](https://ninedof.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/rpi-hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-mini-project/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define TRUE 1

#define TRIG 5
#define ECHO 6

void setup() 
{
        wiringPiSetup();
        pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);

        //TRIG pin must start LOW
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
        delay(30);
}

int getCM() 
{
        //Send trig pulse
        digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(20);
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

        //Wait for echo start
        while(digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);

        //Wait for echo end
        long startTime = micros();
        while(digitalRead(ECHO) == HIGH);
        long travelTime = micros() - startTime;

        //Get distance in cm
        int distance = travelTime / 58;

        return distance;
}

int main(void) 
{
        setup();

        printf("Distance: %dcm\n", getCM());

        return 0;
}
```

While I didn't get any error but I don't get any output.

I used some debugging, like using `printf()` in between statements to check where it gets stuck, so I found that it got stuck at this statement:

```
while(digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);
```

Please help me out why the code is getting stuck there.

Comment: If it's sticking at that line, Pin 6 (ECHO) is never going low - check your wiring, check the sonar device with a voltmeter or scope, or write some test routines outside of this code - it looks like the pin should drop low soon after TRIG goes low. If you have an Arduino, they're great for testing this sort of gadget.

Comment: @MarkWilliams typo, never going high. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=79520